# Steps to trouble shoot "System.AccessViolationException" when calling C++ DLL from VB.NET

Tags: c++, vb.net, dll

I am writing a VB.NET DLL that calls a C++ Dll. The .h file specifies the routine I want to call as;

```
typedef int (EE_STDCALL *Edit_Initialize)(  int* smfID, const char* smf_name, char* smf_init_error, const int error_buffer_size, int* version_compare );
```

I created a reference like;

```
    Declare Function Edit_Initialize Lib "EDITS50.DLL" (ByVal smfID As Integer, ByVal smf_name As String, ByVal smf_init_error As String, ByVal error_buffer_size As Integer, ByRef version_compare As Integer) As Integer
```

I call the routine like;

```
intReturn = Edit_Initialize(_intMFID, strFullMetaFilePath, strErrorReturn, Len(strErrorReturn), intVersionFlag)
```

During execution I get;

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'
```

How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Or if you have any idea as to what I am doing wrong that would be great as well.

Comment: If you are calling a DLL, don't you want to just add a reference to it, and then call it normally?

Comment: Run in the debugger (you may need to specify mixed mode debugging in the project settings).

Comment: The first argument must be ByRef.  You got it right for the last one, somehow, the mechanism is the same.  Technically it could be an array, not so likely.  If it still doesn't work then you troubleshoot it with a telephone.

Comment: @Chuck : Native DLLs cannot be added as a reference. Only .NET DLLs and COM DLLs.

Comment: @HansPassant (or anyone) Is there a way of telling from the line from the .h file which parameters should be called "ByRef" vs "ByVal"? I am writing an awk script that converts the .h to a "globals.vb."  By making the change Hans suggested I get past the first error, but then get an error on the next call.

Comment: Usually anything that is a pointer (a type that has an asterisk after it, for instance `int*`) should be `ByRef`. There are some exceptions to this however, the most common being: `char*` (which maps to a `String`), `wchar_t*` (which maps to a `StringBuilder`), and miscellaneous _**unknown**_ types (which usually maps to `IntPtr`).